# Javascript | Callback and null variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writting a small code to log a variable from a callback. So far my code looks like this.

```js
function Run() {
  GetNumber();
  ShowNumber(); //--> (1)
}

Run();

var numero = null;

function GetNumber() {
  numero = 12;

  setTimeout(function() {
    ShowNumber(); //--> (2)
  }, 2000);
}

function ShowNumber() {
  console.log(numero);
}
```

Notice the (1) and (2). 
When (1) is called, the log is "12" as expected.
But when (2) is called after 2 seconds, it doesn't work and throws this in the console:

```
null
```

I've tried adding bind(this) to the annonymous callback but still, the same error. Why is this happening?.

Comment: First question.  Does `document.querySelector('.MyNavClass')` match anything?

Comment: I'm NOT surprised it isn't working at 2 -- I'm wondering why it *is* working at 1. using document.querySelector() doesn't give the element an open function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ignoring that the element most likely will not have an open function, unless a plugin is involved, the null issue is 99% related to the element not being found.  http://jsfiddle.net/frco1dqx/

Comment: @Taplar if the element isn't found, how would the call at (1) work then?

Comment: Ok, edited to show a much simpler reproduction of the issue.

Comment: What do you mean, how would it work?  It would make the call and get the null pointer inside there.  Both #1 and #2 are going to result in the null pointer.

Comment: @Taplar but OP says that the call at (1) works, "the sidenav opens as expected".

Comment: Well, lets ditch that discussion because the question just changed from selecting an element all together.....

Comment: LOL, this is a case of using things before the variables are declared!!!

Comment: Yeah was that, I've been using JS for years but always using object and (this.variable). But now I'm required to do a program without objects and well, you see what happened LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is the order in which you declare your var.

```js
//declare your variable before the run method, so that when the numero
//is changed inside the GetNumber method, it will change this variable
//declaring it after the run, makes it set it back to null after the run
//finishes.
var numero = null;

function Run() {

  GetNumber();
  ShowNumber(); //--> (1)
}

Run();



function GetNumber() {
  numero = 12;

  setTimeout(function() {
    ShowNumber(); //--> (2)
  }, 2000);
}

function ShowNumber() {
  console.log(numero);
}
```

You could also declare it right before `Run();` and it would work as well.

Comment: Wow i've never thought of a scenario like this. It has never happened to me. Good catch!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was used to the this.variables, so I never knew until now that declaration order is important when not using this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is hoisting and variables being declared as globals. Moving the var before everything fixes your issue.

Your code basically looks like this when it runs.

```
var numero = 12;
console.log(numero)
numero = null;
console.log(numero)
```

So when you change the code order like this:

```js
var numero = null;

function Run() {

  GetNumber();
  ShowNumber(); //--> (1)
}

Run();


function GetNumber() {
  numero = 12;

  setTimeout(function() {
    ShowNumber(); //--> (2)
  }, 2000);
}

function ShowNumber() {
  console.log(numero);
}
```

Comment: One minute late, but yeah, that was the problem. Thank you!.

Comment: actually one minute ahead in the comments... lol I really do not care about the imaginary points. I would of been same time if I did not go back and add the explaination. :)